# How to work as a team on FlexBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, flexbuilder

As me and my friend are working on the same source code of a project on flex builder, I'm looking for a solution that makes it possible to work on different computers and edit the same source code.

Comment: Are you looking for a collaborative editor à la Google Docs?

Comment: Thanks. I were about to ask the same question it aswell +1 / +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use some of the version control system (VCS). More info about it is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). As for me personally, I prefer to use [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). It is convenient and reliable. To work with it right from Eclipse (Flash Builder) you can use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) or [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plugins. You can set up Subversion server on the one of the computers where everybody of the team member can have access.

Comment: yes i'm working with SVN but the problem is that i have to comit every time??

Comment: Yes. But what you're expecting?

Comment: something that could show your friend what are you doing at the same time

Comment: @Manoel - that's the idea of a VCS. You get used to it; the commit is the signal that "hey I was creating some code, and it's now good enough to be shared with (and used by) everyone else" - whatever "good enough" means to your team. Usually it means something like "compiles, tested by me, has some level of automated testing."

Answer (score 0):

Any version control system would work. Try CVS or SVN, the both have client for eclipse (which is flex builder)

Answer (score 0):

Subversion and Subclipse is the ideal team solution for you. What you're asking for (some type of linked real-time editor) doesn't really exist anywhere (and probably wouldn't be terribly useful, otherwise we'd already be doing it).

So I think the answer to your question is, you just need to coordinate, plan, and communicate and divide up work so that you aren't stepping on each other's code changes. A decent architecture that doesn't cause your code updates to clash all the time is key. (Try dividing the project up into "modules" or sub-components, or even better (if this is applicable), just have one person focus on server-side dev (Java, Coldfusion, or whatever) and have the other worry about the Flex UI. This is one of the easier methods of keeping your client and server code somewhat decoupled, of course you still need to communicate and plan regarding the service interface.